# Why used index but the sql is still slow

Tags: sql, oracle11g

There is a table `ORG_HLD_INFO` and there is an index of it: `"ORG_HLD_INFO" ("HLD_UNI_CODE", "ISVALID", "ORG_UNI_CODE")`. Now execute below query is slow, need 3.26 seconds(and all rows fetched is 466)

```
select HLD_UNI_CODE ,ORG_UNI_CODE
from ORG_HLD_INFO
where ISVALID=1 and HLD_UNI_CODE in (30004536568,...)
```

why is so slow? it should use the index, and all the fields of select in the index so no need to query the table row.

p.s.
the total count of the table is: `109102083`
and below is the explain plan

[image]

Comment: How many values are in the `in (30004536568,...) ` clause? If it is more than a few, then index is pretty much useless.

Comment: is this a composite index ?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Thanks! usually around 100 but why in this case the index is useless and how could improve it?

Comment: Can you provide a SQL Monitor report of the execution. Until you know what is going on, everything is just a guess...

Comment: @BobC Have added the explain plan

Comment: @zhuguowei A SQL Monitor report is a bit different than an explain plan.  It provides additional information, such as the actual number of rows and time, instead of just estimates.  If you run `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('your SQL_ID') from dual;` it should provide a text based format you can post here.

Answer (score 1):

You said in comments that your `IN` clause may have around 100 values.

In this case an index in usually useless.

Let's have a look at a simplified version of your query

```
select HLD_UNI_CODE ,ORG_UNI_CODE
from ORG_HLD_INFO
where ISVALID=1 and HLD_UNI_CODE in (3, 4, 5)
```

This is equivalent to

```
select HLD_UNI_CODE ,ORG_UNI_CODE
from ORG_HLD_INFO
where ISVALID=1 and 
    (HLD_UNI_CODE = 3 OR HLD_UNI_CODE = 4 OR HLD_UNI_CODE = 5)
```

This is equivalent to

```
select HLD_UNI_CODE ,ORG_UNI_CODE
from ORG_HLD_INFO
where ISVALID=1 and HLD_UNI_CODE = 3

UNION ALL

select HLD_UNI_CODE ,ORG_UNI_CODE
from ORG_HLD_INFO
where ISVALID=1 and HLD_UNI_CODE = 4

UNION ALL

select HLD_UNI_CODE ,ORG_UNI_CODE
from ORG_HLD_INFO
where ISVALID=1 and HLD_UNI_CODE = 5
```

Here we can use `UNION ALL`, because we include `HLD_UNI_CODE` in the selected columns. If it wasn't we may need to use `UNION`.

Anyway, the point is that each of the individual simple queries like

```
select HLD_UNI_CODE ,ORG_UNI_CODE
from ORG_HLD_INFO
where ISVALID=1 and HLD_UNI_CODE = 5
```

**can** use the index. Use, in the sense that engine will seek in the index to find only the needed rows instead of scanning all rows.

In some databases an optimizer may be smart enough to rewrite the `IN`/ `OR` query into an `UNION` of simpler index seeks (if there are only few values in the `IN`). I don't know if Oracle's optimizer can do this kind of transformation at all.

But, when you have hundreds of such simpler queries it quickly becomes too expensive to do all of these seeks and then put them together, so optimizer opts into scanning the whole table; and scanning the table (or the index) still means reading all 109102083 rows and applying the filter to each row.

You can see in the plan `RANGE SCAN`, not seek, which essentially means reading all rows. And you can see Predicate (filter) with a bunch of `OR`s.

You can try to rewrite your query into hundred unions and check if it runs faster, but the query may become too complicated to parse. So, even if you try to do this transformation manually it may not be feasible, unless you find some trick, like run hundred of simple queries in a loop and dump intermediate results into a temp table.

Comment: Thanks! Does global partitioned indexes help in this case?

Comment: @zhuguowei, I don't have experience with partitioned indexes, but I doubt they can help. If you can put the list of values from your `IN` clause into a table, then it may be possible to rewrite the query to "force" optimizer to do hundred seeks. The key idea that I'd try to use is the so called lateral join. I don't know much about Oracle, but it should support it. I don't know the exact syntax for Oracle, though. You'd better ask another question. There is no guarantee that it would be faster than full scan, though.